# Using kinect for medical application but without computer. Is it possible?

Tags: microcontroller, kinect

I have to use kinect for an application. However,  the final work must be mobile: it means no computer. Consequently, I thought using a microcontroller to handle data from kinect. But is it possible? My job is mesuring some points of a body (axis X, Y, Z) and get back these coordinates. I don't know if I'm enough accurate.

Comment: Depending on the processing you need to do, I know there are many people using the kinect with microcontroller sized computers like the NVidia Jetson and one of the Odroid boards. I don't know much about them though but you might get lucky searching for "NVidia Jetson and Kinect" and find some good write ups.

Comment: What do mean with "medical application"

Comment: I have to mesure some parts of the body in order to jauge the balance.

Comment: And how you can identify the important points?
Do this points have specific color?

Answer (score 1):

There MCU which provide enough calculation power. I'd say "the bigger, the better". For example a ARM-CORTEX M4

This is enough with you just want to extract some coordinates

The protocol of the kinect is pretty simple (http://openkinect.org/wiki/Protocol_Documentation). You can easily implement a communication between the Kinect and the MCU

Answer (score 0):

There are some microcontrollers which can act as a USB host, E.G. [NXP LPC4357](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/LPC4357_53_37_33.pdf). However, microcontrollers tend to have very little RAM. The LPC4357 for example has only 136kB. If you use all of this to store an image, you'd only be able to store a resolution of 373x373 pixels!  The USB host stack and other code are probably going to need quite a bit too.

My advice would be to use a small computer which can do the job, E.G. [Raspberry Pi](http://jonmacey.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/raspberry-pi-and-kinect.html). These tend to have many megabytes of RAM, they run Linux and you can get drivers for them. They aren't big (compared to a Kinect), and fairly low power.